# The directory name is invalid

Tags: c#, windows-services, directory

Why am I getting this error? I am using the correct path.

[image: Directory name is invalid]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Problem :** You are providing the Path of `File`

**Solution :** You need to provide the path of `Directory` to get all the files in a given `Directory` based on your search pattern.

From MSDN: [Directory.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Returns the names of files (including their paths) that match the
>   specified search pattern in the specified directory.

Try this:

```
string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath);
foreach(String filename in Directory.GetFiles(directoryName,"*.eps"))
{   
    //your code here   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the directory, not the filename.

At the moment, the value of `e.FullPath` is `"C:\\DigitalAssets\\LP_10698.eps"`. It should be `"C:\\DigitalAssets"`.

`string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(string path)` requires a directory, you are giving it a directory + filename.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Returns the names of files (including their paths) that match the
>   specified search pattern **in the specified directory**.

```
foreach(string filename in Directory.GetFiles(e.FullPath, "*.eps"))
{
    // For this to work, e.FullPath needs to be a directory, not a file.
}
```

You can use [Path.GetDirectoryName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1):

```
foreach(string filename in Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath), "*.eps"))
{
    // Path.GetDirectoryName gets the path as you need
}
```

You could create a method:

```
public string GetFilesInSameFolderAs(string filename)
{        
    return Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(filename), Path.GetExtension(filename));
}

foreach(string filename in GetFilesInSameFolderAs(e.FullPath))
{
    // do something with files.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is also correct but because @sudhakar answered first so I just upvoted this.

Answer (score 0):

`Directory.GetFiles` used to get file names from particular directory. You are trying to get files from file name which is not valid as it gives you error. Provide directory name to a function instead of file name.

You can try

```
Directory.GetFiles(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath),"*.eps")
```

Answer (score 0):

`e.FullPath` seems to be a file, not a directory. If you want to enumerate *.eps files, the first argument to GetFiles should be a directory path: `@"C:\DigitalAssets"`

Answer (score 0):

the first argument of GetFiles should be only "C:\DigitalAssets" 
e.FullPath include the file name in it.

Answer (score 0):

For deleting files from a directory

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory)
foreach(var file in files)
{
  File.Delete(file);
}
```

In short to delete the file use

```
File.Delete(filePath);
```

and to delete the directory

```
Directory.Delete(directoryPath)
```